# retrieving action attrubute of form in django view

Tags: django, proxy-server

In my proxy app, I want to retrieve the action of submitted form but I can't find any attribute in request object passed to the view.
I tried `request.path` but it's incomplete. for example if true action of form was [/proxy/?url=http://www.farsnews.com](http:///proxy/?url=http://www.farsnews.com), the value of `request.path` is [/proxy/](http:///proxy/) that is obviously useless.
I searched the other attributes of request object but didn't help.

Comment: If you have a form it should be in the form object itself. Please show us your view code.

Comment: Why is that "obviously incorrect"? Looks right to me; the path component of that URL is indeed `/proxy/`.

Comment: the code in UI side is not my code! this is a proxy site and I show contents of a external site and rewrite links and form-actions ,...

Comment: @DanielRoseman, incorrect changed to useless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The querystring parameters, which are also known as GET parameters, are available via `request.GET`. This is fully covered in the [documentation for the request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

Comment: Thanks! request.get_full_path() was what I need